# What does this bitwise expression do?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

`n & (n>>1)`

Where can I use the above expression? I was doing [this](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/just-find-the-next-number/activity/) problem and I saw [this](https://www.hackerearth.com/submission/2254288/) solution to problem where the expression is used.

Problem-

```
You are given an integer n find its next greater or equal number whose    
binary representation must not contain consecutive ones.
```

code-

```
main()
{
int t,n;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--)
{
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while((n&(n>>1)))
    {
        n++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",n);
}
}
```

Comment: The expression says logically `AND` together `n` and `n` with its bits shifted to the right by one.  So anywhere you would do this your expression would come in handy.  If you post the code which used this expression, more could probably be said.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It checks for consecutive ones in `n`. It does a bitwise AND operation on `n` and `n` shifted one bit to the right. If the binary representation of `n` has at least two adjacent ones, you will get something like this:

```
n    :       00001100 
n>>1 :       00000110
---------------------
n & (n>>1) : 00000100
```

Compare this to the original assignment:

> You are given an integer n find its next greater or equal number whose
>   binary representation must not contain consecutive ones.

Answer (score 1):

It is first shift the bits in variable `n` to right

`>>` - Bitwise shift right

Then perform the and operations with the shifted bit..

& - Bitwise and Operation.

here the complete operation is happening like this

consider `int n=6`

so its binary equivalent will be 110 .. and you have to find out next greater than or equal number whose binary equivalent should not contain two consecutive one's in it.

so you that no will be 8 as its binary equivalent is 1000

so if you perform

(n>>1) result will 011

if you do and operation the

```
011
110
```

result will be

```
010
```

now trace your answer code

```
main()
{
 int t,n;
 scanf("%d",&t);
 while(t--)
 {
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while((n&(n>>1)))
    {
        n++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",n);
 }
}
```